# How to get other people or page video thumbnail from facebook?

Tags: api, facebook, video, thumbnails

is there a way you can get video thumbnail from another people video or post? 
I tried searching in google and stackoverflow and all i found is getting your own video thumbnail which is working fine by using `https://graph.facebook.com/v11.0/443055553744880/thumbnails?access_token=my_access_token` but it is not working if i change the video_id to other people video_id (443055553744880 is the video_id). 
 I want to get **any public** video thumbnail regardless of who post it, not just my own video. Is there anyway to do that? 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

No, that is not really possible.

For access to videos on pages you do not have admin access to, you would need the [Page Public Content Access](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/features-reference/page-public-content-access) feature - only the purpose of that is to *“Provide competitive benchmark analysis”*, so it is probably unlikely you would get it approved for other purposes such as to show videos on your site.

And for access to any content on user profiles, you would need the individual user’s permission first.

---

If you just want to show the videos somewhere, then you can use the [Embedded Video & Live Video Player](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/embedded-video-player/) for that, or the [oEmbed endpoints](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/oembed).